# UAP xaml triggers/data-triggers

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I am trying to design a simple tabbed app using universal windows platform (UWP) using **Pivot** control.

I have customized header that includes other controls than just a textblock. I am targeting to change color of those controls/graphics on selection of particular PivotItem using triggers in xaml. Default color updates on selection & hover only apply on textblock but not on other controls.

I can try binding color of other controls with forecolor of textblock because I cannot find template binding not control template in UWP xaml. binding with textblock will still give less space for customization as I am targeting `AccentColor` for header controls/graphics which are defined by MSFT in UAP sdk and we can access them as static resource from `generic.xaml`. e.g. `SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush`. I looked in to xaml triggers as MSFT new xaml architecture allows us to define `VisualStateGroups` and work using `AdaptiveTriggers` & `StateTrigger`. I can't find any other type of triggers like `datatriggers`, `eventtriggers` nothing...

```
<PivotItem>
    <PivotItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Path Stretch="Uniform"
                  Fill="{StaticResource PivotForegroundThemeBrush}"
                  Width="32pt"
                  Height="32pt"
                  Data="M0,33.893959L4.4794149,33.893959 4.4794149,44.677959 48.903614,44.677959 48.903614,33.893959 53.333035,33.893959 53.333035,49.104958 0,49.104958z M24.842734,0L28.513577,0 28.513577,24.615005 35.345016,17.78297 40.346104,17.78297 40.436089,17.883007 26.673088,31.644001 24.072548,29.047991 12.910089,17.883007 13.010208,17.78297 18.001283,17.78297 24.842734,24.615005z"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Downloads"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"
                       FontSize="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </PivotItem.Header>
    <Grid></Grid>
</PivotItem>
```

Comment: So what is the actual question?